# Different font sizes when printing in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, safari

I have a simple website with bootstrap's last version and very little extra css (none in this page in particular) and I found out that when trying to print the same page in Safari and Chrome (mac) I get very different font sizes. In the screenshot I added a fixed font size and line height to the p tags, which is basically what's in the text, yet you can see that in Safari it renders so much smaller (to the right).

How can I fix this?

[image]

P.D.: Of course the page renders exactly the same on the browser, this issue only occurs when printing

P.D.2: I made a test with this very page to see if it is a general issue and it is. I see the same problem, so I'm even more at a loss as to what to do to fix it for my case. Versions are Chrome 37 and Safari 7.0.6

Comment: Do your stylesheets have any `@page` rules for print? In Safari 5 those were seriously broken.

Comment: Nope, none of those, also I checked bootstrap media queries for print and don't seem to be related to the issue

Comment: Well it might be worth a try to add a little `@media print` rule to make sure the font size is explicitly the same.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, same issue.

Comment: Well browser print support is generally really terrible. :(

Comment: Is it something you need to change in your browser settings - ie does safari have a default print font size overriding the style sheet, or is it trying to zoom so it fits the whole document on one page?

Comment: None of it, if I change the font size to something like 60, it will grow up in both browsers but safari will always be smaller than chrome. Maybe if I target Safari and give it a bigger font size than chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my work we have to have very high fidelity prints, so we usually render server-side with either [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (free) or [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/) (commercial but excellent), both of which are dedicated print render engines for HTML. Both generate a PDF, and then the PDF can be downloaded to the browser and printed with consistent results on every platform and browser.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably use that if the client gets too picky, can't think of much else since it seems to be happening in any website